# How to know what type to assign to a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a type mismatch when I substitute `sFolder` (a string type variable that stores a file address) for the actual address typed out. When I type the address out, the code runs fine. When I store the address to a string type variable, I get a type mismatch. I'm a complete beginner with coding, so I am sure this is a simple problem to fix, but I have been searching all over for an answer with no success.

The `sFolder` variable below is a public variable that is declared as a string outside this function.

```
Sub CheckFileTimes()

Dim StrFile As String
Dim StrCDate As Date
Dim fso As Object
Dim f As Object

'set up output file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpentextFile(sFolder & "\TEST.xls", 2, True)

'open folder and loop through
StrFile = Dir(sFolder & "\*.3D*")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
Set objFile = fso.getfile(sFolder \ StrFile) ' THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
'get creation date
StrCDate = objFile.datecreated
'write to output file
f.writeLine StrFile & "," & StrCDate

'move to next file in folder
StrFile = Dir

Loop

f.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this `sFolder & "\" & StrFile`, although I suspect just `StrFile` may suffice.

Comment: @BrianMStafford please post that as an answer (seems small, but fits the bill given the post); this should allow the post to be listed as `Answered`, rather than having people comment searching.

Comment: @Brian Thank you very much! That worked perfectly.

Comment: You're getting a type mismatch because you are telling VBA to divide a string by a string. You can't do that - you can only divide a number by a number. Yes, even the backslash `\\` operator in VBA means divide - but it's a special division that will drop any remainder after the integer result. So as it has been said, you need to turn the operator into a string, and concatenate it between to ampersands.

Comment: In other words, `4 / 3 = 1.33333333~`.... `4 \ 3 = 1`.... `String \ String = Type Mismatch Error`

Comment: @jcm5 please accept Brian's posted answer, as you indicated it did help you, so this question is listed as answered in the question log

Answer (score 1):

Since you are building a string containing a file name, you need to format your code like this:

```
sFolder & "\" & StrFile
```

With this code, you are concatenating 3 strings, instead of doing a division.